# Maximum number limitation of COM+ function parameters

Tags: delphi, com+, typelib

I was using Delphi Type Library to create a COM+ application. I got a access violation error when I created the number 78 parameters for one function call. I realized that there is a limitation for the number of parameters for the COM+ functions. So after, I have to use a typed structure/Record to package the parameters. Then pass a record instead of numbers of simple data type parameters.

Do you know about this limitation and what is your suggest?

I did more test as involved the Struct/Record, then I install the new component and get a error when I call it:

[image: Type Library with the Record]

I call the function:

```
ReturnVaule := Clients.updClient2(EmploymentApp.SessionID,
                                MyClientDetails,
                                dtLastModificationDate,
                                ClientServices,
                                ClientRequestors,
                                ClientQuestionnaires);
```

and I get the error:

> "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub"

[image: error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I use a Variant parameter to transfer most of the parameters, then read them out as a array. It works fine, but it is not easy to know the index of the array is mapping to which parameter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that there is any such limit in Delphi or COM+. I'm not sure what caused your error but I think you'd need to describe what you did in more detail.

No matter what, it is not sensible to have methods with that many parameters. More than about 4 or 5 is already stretching it. Take this incident as a gentle hint to rethink your design in a more manageable manner.

Comment: The reason I believe the error is cause by the number of parameter is because: If I add any type of parameter to the 78th, error raised. If I delete the last one, the error will disappear. The reason I put a lot parameters is because the COM+ function will not accept any customized class or type as a parameter type.

Comment: A COM+ function will accept a record (struct) parameter type declared in your type library.

Comment: "You cannot use user defined datatypes in the parameters for the methods which are exposed to the outside world. Instead you can use the Safearrays supported by VARIANT. " This is what I found and tested to be reasonable.

Comment: You cannot realistically expose methods with that many parameters to the outside world. It is inhumane to do so. What would should contemplate instead is passing these parameters in a separate COM object with all the parameters exposed as properties. I expect you have hit upon an IDE bug rather than a limitation in COM+ or Delphi. But you didn't yet say where the AV occurs. Is it in the Delphi IDE or is it at runtime?

Comment: I tested this in Delphi 5 and Delphi XE2 (the newest). They both have the same problem with the "type library". So I can say the IDE does not catch this error. On the other hand, I remove the {$R *.TLB} which means I will not use type library and setup every thing manually. Then I can put more parameters, compile and build successfully. But, I cannot make it run with Component Service.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this in the IDE. Perhaps it's something about the types you are using for parameters.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you can use the type library editor to declare your record type and then modify your method to use a parameter of that type.

Edit: Example screenshot from the type library editor:

[image]

The type library declarations from the type library editor generates the following code (excerpt):

```
type

// *********************************************************************//
// Forward declaration of types defined in TypeLibrary
// *********************************************************************//
  ITest = interface;
  ITestDisp = dispinterface;

// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of CoClasses defined in Type Library
// (NOTE: Here we map each CoClass to its Default Interface)
// *********************************************************************//
  Test = ITest;


// *********************************************************************//
// Declaration of structures, unions and aliases.
// *********************************************************************//
  TestRecord = packed record
    Field1: Integer;
    Field2: WideString;
    Field3: TDateTime;
  end;


// *********************************************************************//
// Interface: ITest
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {F3EA5C38-23A6-4919-A51F-31C46DB6012D}
// *********************************************************************//
  ITest = interface(IDispatch)
    ['{F3EA5C38-23A6-4919-A51F-31C46DB6012D}']
    procedure TestMethod(TestParam: TestRecord); safecall;
  end;

// *********************************************************************//
// DispIntf:  ITestDisp
// Flags:     (4416) Dual OleAutomation Dispatchable
// GUID:      {F3EA5C38-23A6-4919-A51F-31C46DB6012D}
// *********************************************************************//
  ITestDisp = dispinterface
    ['{F3EA5C38-23A6-4919-A51F-31C46DB6012D}']
    procedure TestMethod(TestParam: {??TestRecord}OleVariant); dispid 201;
  end;
```

Comment: In fact, after many test, I found the only thing I can use is Variant. Maybe I can use a interface too, but it will need more coding efforts.

Comment: You can simply define the record type in the type library, using the type library editor.